# Downcast an object, that is declared in a base class, in the inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm creating a plug-in for an API and have problems with inheritance. Is there a way to "automatically" downcast an object, that is declared in a base class, in a class inherited from it?

My class structure is as follows:

```
abstract class MyPart
{
    public Part modelObject;
    ...
}

class MyPlate : MyPart
{
    public ArraList points; // from API
    ...
}

class Floor : MyPlate
{
    ...
}
```

`Part` is an API class whose class structure is something like the following:

```
class Part
class Plate : Part
```

Now, in my code in `MyPlate` and `Floor` classes I need to use `Plate modelObject` to get access to it's methods. Currently I do this by downcasting `modelObject`:

```
(modelObject as Plate).doSomething;
```

This kinda works, though I would like to make it simpler. The main problem, however, is that when I try to access the members of `modelObject` I can't get them as references. For example when I try to declare `points` it doesn't reference `modelObject.points`:

```
points = (modelObject as Plate).points;
points = null; // modelObject.points != null
```

Is there a way to declare variables as references to `modelObject` so that they could be manipulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually two questions. The part, why your points won't get deleted has already been answered. But for completeness, here the summary:

### Deleting Refrences

When you call `var points = (modelObject as Plate).points`, you copy a reference to the `points` object of `modelObject`. With `points = null` you just remove (null) the reference to the `points` of `modelObject`, but `modelObject` still keeps a reference to `points`.

To delete `modelObject`'s reference to `points`, call `(modelObject as Plate).points = null`.

### Downcasting in Sub-Class

But to your main question, how to automatically downcast an object in the subclass. There are two ways to achieve this. *Method Hiding* and *Generics*:

**Method Hiding**

Methhides a method or another member of the baseclass, and provides a new meaning to a name. That way, you can give the subclass-member another meaning and another return type. To achieve this, you should encapsulate modelObject in a Property. Your code would like this:

```
abstract class MyPart
{
    private Part modelObject;
    public Part ModelObject 
    {
       get { return modelObject; }
       set { modelObject = value; }
    }
    ...
}

class MyPlate : MyPart
{
    public new Plate ModelObject 
    {
        get { return base.ModelObject as Plate; }
        set { base.ModelObject = value; }
    public ArraList points; // from API
    ...
}

class Floor : MyPlate
{
    ...
}
```

Notice, the use of `base.ModelObject` in the subclass. This enables you to still access the base-classes ModelObject, although you have given a new meaning to ModelObject. Other than method overriding, you keep the base classes Member and only provide another meaning with the same name.

Watch out, this has some implications. The most important one is, that a class does not know, if a member is hidden in a subclass, which means, that a subclass, casted to the base class, will always run the base-class-functionality. See the following code-sample for illustration purposes.

```
public class Base 
{
    public void Do() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}
public class Sub : Base
{
    public new void Do() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sub");
    }
}
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        Base base = sub;

        sub.Do(); //prints Sub
        base.Do(); //prints Base, even though it is the same object.
    }
}
```

**Generics**

With generics on the other hand, you can parametrize the type of Plate with a type-parameter (`TPlate` in the example). This is slightly more complicated, but also the cleaner way, since subclassing and casting has no confusing effects like method hiding.

```
abstract class MyPart<TPart> 
    where TPart : Part //configure a type parameter
{
    public TPart modelObject;
    ...
}

class MyPlate : MyPart<Plate> //TPlate is now of type Plate
{
    public ArraList points; // from API
    ...
}

class Floor : MyPlate
{
    ...
}
```

The above example doesn't allow MyFloor to further specialize the Type Parameter, but this can also be achieved:

```
abstract class MyPart<TPart> 
    where TPart : Part //configure a type parameter and force it to be a subclass of Part
{
    public TPart modelObject;
    ...
}

class MyPlate<TPlate> : MyPart<TPlate> 
    where TPlate : Plate //force the type parameter to be a subclass of Plate
{
    public ArraList points; // from API
    ...
}

class Floor : MyPlate<Floor> //TType is now Floor
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using generics would have been great, but it introduces a problem with casting in other parts of the program. The program relies on casting between `MyPart`s and `Floor`s which can't be done if `MyPart` is generic.

Method hiding works fine here. My wish was primarily to simplify the `(modelObject as Plate)` part and `ModelObject` looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a copy of the **reference**. `points = (modelObject as Plate).points;` So `points` and `(modelObject as Plate).points` points to the same memory. When you assign `null` to `points`, one reference is cleared. The other still exists.

If you want the `(modelObject as Plate).points;` to be null. Just use: `(modelObject as Plate).points = null;`

This doesn't have anything to do with casting.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `points` to `null` there you're nulling out the reference named "points" in the scope, not the actual variable. You want to manipulate it by ref to actually access that if you really don't want to just do `modelObject.points = null` (which you'd normally just do).

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

That said, I'm not sure why you're downcasting the objects as we can't see enough of what's going on to determine that here.